# How to Get count of active employees (in all months)

Tags: sql, oracle, fusion

I am trying to create HCM Report in (Fusion BI Reports) to retrieve the count of employees for 'all months' of the selected year.

In the current case when we run the report on '2017' it retrieves the total count of employees in July, August, Sept

What is required :
When the parameter = '2017' AND the months after Sept are null then get the last existing value which is in 'Sept'

```
Month Name   Current result    Expected result
July          1                 1
Aug           3                 3 
Sept          4                 4
Oct                             4
Nov                             4
Dec                             4
```

my query

```
SELECT PIVOT_TBL.* FROM
(SELECT
        COUNT(PAPF.PERSON_ID) OVER (ORDER BY  TO_CHAR(PAPF.START_DATE,'MM-YYYY')) AS OP_BALANCE,
        EXTRACT (MONTH FROM PAPF.START_DATE)  AS OMONTHS


 FROM
        PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F          PAPF,
        PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M     PAAM,   
        PER_PERSONS               PP  

WHERE     
        PAAM.PERSON_ID              =  PAPF.PERSON_ID
    AND PP.PERSON_ID                =  PAPF.PERSON_ID  
    ------------------------------------------------ 
    AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE        =  'E'
    AND PAAM.PRIMARY_FLAG           =  'Y'  
    AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y' 
    AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE  = 'ACTIVE'
    -------------------------------------------------
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    AND  PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE 
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE    AND  PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE  
    AND TO_CHAR(PAPF.START_DATE,'YYYY')='2017'
    ORDER BY 2)SRC_TABLE

    PIVOT
    (MAX(OP_BALANCE) AS EJ FOR OMONTHS IN
    ('1' AS JAN , '2' AS FEB , '3' AS MAR , '4'  AS APR , '5'  AS MAY , '6'  AS JUNE ,
     '7' AS JUL , '8' AS AUG , '9' AS SEPT, '10' AS OCTO, '11' AS NOV , '12' AS DECE)
    )PIVOT_TBL
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure all the months are present somehow, then use the `LAST_VALUE()` function with `IGNORE NULLS` to copy the last non-null value down the later months.

```
var yr number;
exec :yr := 2017;
with raw_results(dte, rslt) as (
  select date '2017-07-01', 1 from dual union all
  select date '2017-08-01', 3 from dual union all
  select date '2017-09-01', 4 from dual
)
, min_dte as (
  select min(dte) dte from raw_results
  where dte >= trunc(to_date(:yr,'yyyy'), 'yy')
)
, months as (
  select add_months(dte, level-1) dte
  from min_dte
  connect by extract(year from add_months(dte, level-1)) = :yr
)
select to_char(dte, 'Mon') "Month", 
  last_value(rslt ignore nulls) over(order by dte) "Result"
from months
left join raw_results using(dte);

Month            Result
------------ ----------
Jul                   1
Aug                   3
Sep                   4
Oct                   4
Nov                   4
Dec                   4
```

Comment: ERROR: SQL query time exceeds the limit (500). Stopped processing.

Comment: great solution.

Answer (score 0):

connect by extract(year from add_months(dte, level-1)) = :yr
)
select to_char(dte, 'Mon') "Month",
last_value(rslt ignore nulls) over(order by dte) "Result"
from months
left join raw_results using(dte);

Month            Result

---

Jul                   1
Aug                   3
Sep                   4
Oct                   4
Nov                   4
Dec                   4